How to pass symmetric key to query
I want to know how to pass symmetric key to SQL query as parameter.
I'm usually hardcoding it within the query as follows:
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE CertiFi;

SELECT * FROM MasterBlaster

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey

But I want to pass it as parameter.

According to the documentation you can't use parameters or variables in OPEN KEY statement. One way to do it is:
declare @key nvarchar(100) = 'test'
, @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = N'
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY ' + QUOTENAME(@key) + N'
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE CertiFi;

SELECT * FROM MasterBlaster;

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY ' + QUOTENAME(@key) + N';'
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL

Note that you gotta be careful with SQL injection, therefore QUOTENAME is used
